# Cannot trigger Azure data factory pipeline on blob creation

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-eventgrid

I want to trigger a data factory pipeline when a blob is created.

Following the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger), I am getting an error.

I have enabled EventGrid and DataFactory on the subscription. The data factory is set to Owner role for the entire storage account (using the new RBAC interface where you dont enter the managed object id, you just browse the names of your resources). Nothing has been done to the container level security. For storage account settings, under Firewalls and Virtual Networks, it is set to allow access from All Networks. I don't have any vnets or other virtual networking constructs defined in the resource group.

In the same data factory, I can create data sets that point to the same container, and can test connection and browse data just fine. But when trying to create the trigger, I am seeing this:

"Unable to list files and show data preview (...)"
[error in data preview pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOtqH.png)

I am the person who created the resource group and all of these resources. All resources are created in the same region (US Central.) Everything has been done through the Azure portal.

Comment: Not sure if you have already checked this . Its in the same doc which you have mentioned .

"The Event Trigger currently supports only Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and General-purpose version 2 storage accounts. Due to an Azure Event Grid limitation, Azure Data Factory only supports a maximum of 500 event triggers per storage account.

Comment: The storage account is General-purpose version 2